Unable to Render Quarto Document
# First we create a subset of data that we want a summary of.
selected_vars <- c("y0age", "y1sex", "y1gen", "y1racm", "y0scr06", "y1eco")
dem_data <- subset(data, select = selected_vars)

# We need to convert labelled data into factors. 
dem_data <- dem_data %>%
  mutate(across(c(y1sex, y1gen, y1racm, y0scr06, y1eco), ~ haven::as_factor(.)))

dem_data$y0age <- as.numeric(dem_data$y0age)

dem_table <- gtsummary::tbl_summary(
    dem_data,
    include = c(y0age, y1sex, y1gen, y1racm, y0scr06, y1eco),
    missing = "no",
    type = (list(
      y0age ~ "continuous2")
    ),
        statistic = list(
      all_continuous() ~ "{mean} ({sd})",
      all_categorical() ~ "{n} ({p}%)"
    ),
    digits = list(
      all_continuous() ~ 2,
      all_categorical() ~ c(0, 2)),
    label = list(
      y0age ~ "Age",
    y1sex ~ "Sex Assigned at Birth",
    y1gen ~ "Gender Identity",
    y1racm ~ "Racial Identity",
    y0scr06 ~ "Sexual Orientation",
    y1eco ~ "Financial Hardship"))

Above here is the lines 122-160.
processing file: Hope_Moderation.qmd
  |...................                                |  36% [unnamed-chunk-6] 
Quitting from lines  at lines 122-160 [unnamed-chunk-6] (Hope_Moderation.qmd)
Error in `.make_numeric_version()`:
! invalid non-character version specification 'x' (type: double)
Backtrace:
  1. global .main()
  2. execute(...)
  3. rmarkdown::render(...)
  4. knitr::knit(knit_input, knit_output, envir = envir, quiet = quiet)
  5. knitr:::process_file(text, output)
     ...
 26. flextable:::is_in_quarto()
 28. base::Ops.numeric_version(...)
 29. base::as.numeric_version(e1)
 30. base::numeric_version(x)
 31. base::.make_numeric_version(x, strict, .standard_regexps()$valid_numeric_version)
                                                                                                             
Execution halted

sessionInfo()
R version 4.4.0 (2024-04-24)
Platform: aarch64-apple-darwin20
Running under: macOS Sonoma 14.4.1
Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.4-arm64/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib;  LAPACK version 3.12.0
locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8
time zone: America/New_York
tzcode source: internal
attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
other attached packages:
[1] jtools_2.2.2       rempsyc_0.1.7      flextable_0.9.5    apaTables_3.0.0    correlation_0.8.4  gtsummary_1.7.2    modelsummary_2.0.0 haven_2.5.4        lubridate_1.9.3    forcats_1.0.0      stringr_1.5.1      dplyr_1.1.4        purrr_1.0.2        readr_2.1.5        tidyr_1.3.1        tibble_3.2.1       ggplot2_3.5.1      tidyverse_2.0.0
loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] gtable_0.3.5            xfun_0.43               bayestestR_0.13.2       insight_0.19.10         papaja_0.1.2            tzdb_0.4.0              vctrs_0.6.5             tools_4.4.0             interactions_1.1.5      generics_0.1.3          datawizard_0.10.0       curl_5.2.1              fansi_1.0.6             pkgconfig_2.0.3         data.table_1.15.4       uuid_1.2-0              gt_0.10.1               lifecycle_1.0.4         compiler_4.4.0          textshaping_0.3.7       munsell_0.5.1           tinylabels_0.2.4        httpuv_1.6.15           fontquiver_0.2.1        fontLiberation_0.1.0    htmltools_0.5.8.1       later_1.3.2             pillar_1.9.0            crayon_1.5.2            gfonts_0.2.0            broom.helpers_1.15.0    openssl_2.1.2           mime_0.12               fontBitstreamVera_0.1.1 tidyselect_1.2.1        zip_2.3.1               digest_0.6.35           stringi_1.8.3           pander_0.6.5            fastmap_1.1.1           grid_4.4.0              colorspace_2.1-0        cli_3.6.2               magrittr_2.0.3          crul_1.4.2              utf8_1.2.4              broom_1.0.5             withr_3.0.0             backports_1.4.1         gdtools_0.3.7           scales_1.3.0            promises_1.3.0          timechange_0.3.0        rmarkdown_2.26          officer_0.6.5           hms_1.1.3               askpass_1.2.0           ragg_1.3.0              shiny_1.8.1.1           evaluate_0.23           knitr_1.46              parameters_0.21.6       rlang_1.1.3             Rcpp_1.0.12             xtable_1.8-4            glue_1.7.0              httpcode_0.3.0          xml2_1.3.6              rstudioapi_0.16.0       jsonlite_1.8.8          effectsize_0.8.7        R6_2.5.1                tables_0.9.25           systemfonts_1.0.6


Problem:
I updated to the new R, which was a mistake, and now I can't seem to render this quarto document. To be clear, it was able to run before the update, and can even run in Rmarkdown document.
The error seems to suggest it has to do with the type of data I'm working with. I have imported a .sav file (SPSS data) using haven. I just don't understand what the issue is.

I have the same error. I couldn't stop my work, so I sent it to previous Rmarkdown and it worked perfectly and with a bonus. I was rendering the document to word format, but the outcome allways came with some formating issues and I had to "Save as" everytime. Rmarkdown solved this and saved me a lot of wasted time. It still seems more stable than quarto.
Checking further, my problem seems to come from the use of the flextable package, but still...

Try updating flextable to at least version 0.9.6

@Steve: Why not?

@Steve what about my solution to the problem is unclear to you?

Because it looks like more a comment than an answer (instead of try ... you should write if you update to xxxx it should work) However I admit that your post could be considered an answer, so please [edit] your post and I can remove the downvote
